# Infyom Laravel Generator - Yajra DataTable - Rigth align numeric values

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, yajra-datatable, infyom

Does anyone know how to right align columns with numeric value with infyom laravel-generator yajra datatable.

From this [Doc](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/html-builder-column) you have add the render parameter, but I did not find a solution to add it with Infyom.

Thank in advance.

Comment: I see that, when you publish the templates, there is a [stub](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/blob/develop/templates/scaffold/datatable.stub) that seems to have the parameters you need to modify to do what you want. Try to ALWAYS see the source code as it is open source and it is the source of truth. Maybe you are missing publishing the assets, hence you cannot see that file, read the package documentation.

Comment: Can you be more precise in your comment, I don't see how to do it with this file.

Comment: In the stub I have shared in my first comment, you can see there is a method called `protected function getColumns()`. In the documentation you shared, you need to edit the `columns` array, hence, the resulting array inside that method is what you want to edit. When you publish the file, it will get populated and you will be able to edit what you want. [This](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/blob/e3a40c24075cfa839b58b4e5fb519ce921472a0d/src/Generators/Scaffold/ControllerGenerator.php#L81-L145) is the command populating those fields once published...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still not clear for me, don't undertsand where to put the data ('rigth align') in order to be read by the function 'generateDataTableColumns'. I have to leave and be back tomorrow ... if you can be still more precise thanks inadvance.

Comment: I read the source code a little more and it is pretty complex without me installing it and stuff, so I will not be able to help you as it will take me a lot of time and I will not invest into that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your try, for such (generic) question the answer should come from sb who had got already the problem/solution. If not, hope I'll find later and 'll share the result for the community like my previous post on the same 'subject'

Answer (score 0):

in app/DataTables/Your_modelDataTable.php , in the function getColums, change the field defintion

change 'your_field' to

```
'your_field'=>['render'=>'function(){return "<div style="text-align:right;">"+data+"<\div>"}'],
```

[See on GitHub](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator/issues/976)